How to suppress all output from qpOases in terminal
I'm using CasADi with qpOases in a C++ project, solving a qp problem on each iteration. The solver prints a message to the terminal every time it's called.
Using the flags
opts["print_time"]    = false;
opts["printLevel"]    = "none";

helped, but the license notice is still printed every time:
qpOASES -- An Implementation of the Online Active Set Strategy.
Copyright (C) 2007-2015 by Hans Joachim Ferreau, Andreas Potschka,
Christian Kirches et al. All rights reserved.
qpOASES is distributed under the terms of the 
GNU Lesser General Public License 2.1 in the hope that it will be 
useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty 
of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

Is there a way to only output the license message once instead of on every iteration?
According to the qpOASES user's manual the compile flag SUPPRESSANYOUTPUT could be used. How do I set this flag?
Edit:
I haven't specified qpOASIS explicitly in the CMakeLists.txt files. I included the entire CasADi library by cloning the source code than linking to it with:
find_package(casadi REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} casadi)
install(DIRECTORY ../lib/casadi DESTINATION share/my_project_name)

then used cmake -DWITH_QPOASES=ON .. to enable qpOASES.

Can you post the snippet of CMakeLists.txt that incorporates qpOASES in your project?
